# Simultaneous Non-parametric regression and Non-parametric density estimation

Tags: regression, nonparametric

Given a collection of $(x,y)$ data, one might do a non/semiparametric regression of $y$ on $x$ to understand how to predict the $E(Y|X)$.  Similarly, if one has enough data, it might be useful take a narrow vertical slice of the data (a small range of $x$), and try to understand the pdf of $Y$ at that point.  However, I don't have very dense data, so I would like to combine these two techniques.  What I would like to understand is, for any value of $x$, the full distribution of $Y|X$.  I suppose that this really isn't even possible if the densities change rapidly as a function of $x$, but I'm willing to make some assumptions and take some short-cuts (I have a sense that the density is being 'stretched' as $x$ increases, and it should be unimodal though not symmetric) - I'm still trying to get a sense of what I need to assume.  Any advice or references are appreciated.

My only idea so far is to do it iteratively - regress, find the conditional means, estimate the densities, repeat.  There seem to be some shortcomings, though.